# Replace the exact number from line of text even if the number is repeated using regular expression Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have one input file. sample.txt: is a text file that contains multiple functions with parameters and values.

Sample.txt:

```
step(change_lane in [1.5..2]s) # From: 'change_lane: [1.5..2]s'
step(stop_lane in [1.8..21]s) # From: 'stop_lane: [1.5..2]s'
step(stay_lane in [1.7..9]s) # From: 'stay_lane: [1.5..2]s'
The new lane change is == 25
.......
```

My code is the following:

```
for line in open('sample.txt'):
    match = re.search('change_lane', line)
    if match:
        # Finds numbers in line, outputs a list of numbers in line
        x = re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', line)
        
        # Gets first/second number from list
        print(f"This is line: {x}")
        get_num1 = x[0]
        get_num2 = x[1]
       
        #Replace first number found with number 200
        rep_num1 = re.sub(r'\b'+get_num1+r'\b','200',line)
        print(f"Rep1: {rep_num1}")
        #Replace second number found with number 17.21 under new edited line.
        rep_num2 = re.sub(r'\b'+get_num2+r'\b','17.21',rep_num1)
    
        #Old text line will equal to edited line
        line = rep_num2
        print(f"This is the new line: {line}")
```

The code will search through the text and match a phrase in this case "change_lane". If it matches it will find all numbers and output them as a list: [1.5,2,1.5,2].I am only interested in changing the first two numbers as the rest is a comment. Next, I will replace first number in the list with number 200. Now rep_num1 will become the new line as such:

`keep(change_lane in [200..2]s) # From: 'change_lane: [200..2]s`

**help here**: Then, I want the code to replace the number 2 with 17.21 as such:

`keep(change_lane in [200..17.21]s) # From: 'change_lane: [200..17.21]s`

But instead it replaces all number '2's with 17.21 as such:

`keep(change_lane in [17.2100..17.21]s) # From: 'change_lane: [17.2100..17.21]s`

How can I write the regular expression to find the exact number and replace that number even if the number is repeated?

Answer (score 1):

You might use a single pattern to find the right line and then do the replacement for the numbers.

The pattern captures 3 groups that you can use in the replacement. The matches in between the groups are the numbers that you want to replace.

**Explanation**

```
^(.*?\bchange_lane\b.*?\[)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(\.+)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(]s\)\s+#)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Group 1

  - `.*?\bchange_lane\b` Match as least as possible characters until `change_lane`
  - `.*?\[` Match the first occurrence of `[`
- `)` Close group 1
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`  Match the number
- `(\.+)` Group 2, match 1+ dots
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match the second occurrence of the number
- `(]s\)\s+#)` Group 3, match the last part till the `#`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nHYE7M/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"^(.*?\bchange_lane\b.*?\[)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(\.+)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(]s\)\s+#)"

s = ("step(change_lane in [1.5..2]s) # From: 'change_lane: [1.5..2]s'\n"
            "step(stop_lane in [1.8..21]s) # From: 'stop_lane: [1.5..2]s'\n"
            "step(stay_lane in [1.7..9]s) # From: 'stay_lane: [1.5..2]s'\n"
            "The new lane change is == 25")

subst = r"\g<1>200\g<2>17.21\g<3>"

result = re.sub(pattern, subst, s, 0, re.MULTILINE)

print (result)
```

Output

```
step(change_lane in [200..17.21]s) # From: 'change_lane: [1.5..2]s'
step(stop_lane in [1.8..21]s) # From: 'stop_lane: [1.5..2]s'
step(stay_lane in [1.7..9]s) # From: 'stay_lane: [1.5..2]s'
The new lane change is == 25
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there a way to change the regular expression in rep_num2, that would not change the entire code completely, so the regular expression can be precise on the number that is needed to be changed?

Comment: @IanCalle  So you want to be able to get multiple matches before the first `#` ? Do you have an example with `change_lane` ?

Comment: @IanCalle Try `rep_num2 = re.sub(r'^(.*?)\b'+get_num2+r'\b',r'\117.21',rep_num1)`

Comment: I was able to figure it out, thanks to your explanation. I used pattern = (\.\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)? and for sub = \g<1>200